# ProgressBar.Value property not available in Visual Studio 2012 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I’m trying to learn C#. I’m using Visual Studio 2012 Express and WPF in this case.

I’m trying to get the `ProgressBar.Value` property to become available to be used but it won’t come up even though I’ve got the System.Windows.Controls class enabled and defined.

I can select the `ProgressBar.ValueProperty` property though.
I googled it and didn’t come up with any reasons why it’s missing so far…

Comment: Could you post the code that you have? Might make it a lot easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The "Value" dependency property is definitely on progress bars in VS2012 (.NET 4.5). ValueProperty could be the backing property for this DP. Code would be very helpful in trying to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a confusion. You can assign a Value only to instances of ProgressBars, not to the class itself.

```
ProgressBar myProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
myProgressBar.Value = 30;
```

It would be a better idea to start learning first OOP (Object oriented programming) instead of C#.

Comment: no he didn't make a confusion -- see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Do it on the design view, select the ProgressBar go the proprieties panel (right) and look for *Value* you can change it as you want,

Therefore if you want to edit it programmatically : Create your instance ( drag and drop from the toolbox or create it using XAML or C# ) and then access it via code :

```
myProgressBar.Value = 100;
```

XAML creation code :

```
 <ProgressBar x:Name="myProgressBar" Value="100" />
```

Comment: see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)